# Distribution of a general stochastic process composed with an independent random variable throught the index parameter

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose you have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, a finite measure space $(S, \mathcal{S},\mu )$ and the associated product space $(S \times \Omega, \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{F},\mu \times \mathbb{P})$.

Suppose further we have a collection $Y_s:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of random variables indexed by elements $s\in S$. Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow S$ be a random variable with distribution $\nu$ that is independent of the $Y_s$'s.

I want to investigate under what conditions the following equality holds for all $B$ Borel:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left( Y_X \in B \right) = \int_S \mathbb{P} \left(Y_s \in B \right)d\nu(s)
\end{equation}

I've been assuming that the function $f :S \times\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(s,\omega)= Y_s(\omega)$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra. Furthermore, my proof attempts to use the fact that a bounded measurable function $f$ can be approximated in $L^1$ by functions of the form:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m_n}h_{n,i}(s)g_{n,i}(\omega)
\end{equation}
where the the $h$'s and $g$'s are bounded and measurable and in addition the $g$'s are independent of $X$.

Now I can prove the approximation without the independence clause for a general finite measure space $S$ but can only prove the full approximation by tightening $S$ to be a Polish space. Can this be loosened?

Also, does it help to consider the case where the $Y_s$'s and $X$ are all independent?